# Help with translating old signs

Tags: translation

I recently bought an old wooden item that shows 5 traditional (?) Chinese characters. I tried my very best to translate them by researching all kind of pages, but cannot find some parts I need. Can someone help me translate? And now that I learned a little bit about how signs work I would also be very curious about the meaning of the single parts of them.

Here are the pictures (I believe the signs are mirrored, as with stamps for cookies.)

[image: number 1 and 2]
[image: numbers 3 to 5]

Answer (score 2):

The left two should be 壽富, from top to down. The right ones, from top to down again, are likely to be 富貴X. I am sure about the last character, 屋?

Comment: In the left: It's 福 (示 at the top and 畐 at the bottom), not 富.

Comment: May be you are right.

Answer (score 2):

The last one is '居'. 富贵居.

I don't how to translate it, but not everyone's home can be called 居. Usually belong to an educated man.

Answer (score 0):

First four characters should be 喜福富贵, although the last one is a bit tricky.

Comment: The first character is 壽 – the sign is a variant of the seal script. And the last one might be 己丑, which only records the year of the mould and is not supposed to mould a mooncake there.

Comment: Hereby conceded.

Comment: @倪阔乐 ......doesn't have to be so reluctant :( Always welcome to discuss any question with me and point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jacob mentioned, the last character is「居」, and is quite tricky to identify.

「居」([Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*k(r)a/, /*k(r)a-s/**, *to dwell/reside*) is composed of semantic「尸」(*squatting person* > *body*) and phonetic「古」(Baxter-Sagart: **/*kˤaʔ/**). In turn,「古」was originally composed of semantic「盾」(*shield*) and a distinguishing mark「口」. The word originally represented by「古」is now written as「固」(*solid, sturdy*). For reference:

- Glyph evolution of「古」

  ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]
  [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)475
  [合集21242](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21242&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  大盂鼎
  [集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>現代
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>
- Glyph evolution of「盾」

  ## <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [林](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.24.6
  [合集16347](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=16347&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  小臣宅簋
  [集成4201](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4201&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
  金
  [image]
  五年師⿸㫃史
  [集成4216](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4216&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>現代
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

  In the third form, the shield is reduced to a side view, and「目」(*eye*) was added, representing a person peeking out from under the full-body cover of a shield.

In the question photo, the「古」in「居」takes the form where the distinguishing mark「口」has not been added and the full frontal form of the shield has not yet been reduced to a shape like「十」.

Answer (score -1):

from upper left to bottom right. first one is富, second one is 贵, 3-己丑, not sure? 4-寿, 5-福

Comment: From right to left?